# Programa se detiene al contar archivos de un directorio

Tags: c

estoy realizando un programa en c que tiene la funcionalidad de leer los archivos de un directorio y subdirectorios al igual que contar la cantidad de archivos contenidos en el directorio, hasta ahora la función de leer archivos funciona bien.

el problema radica en la función de contar archivos, cuando llega a la función, el programa termina la ejecución y no se porque, no muestra ningún mensaje de error solo se detiene, agradecería la ayuda.

Este es mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

int total_archivos(DIR *directory){
    int  numfile = 0;
    struct dirent *ent = NULL;
    while( (ent = readdir(directory)) != NULL ){
        if ( (strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") != 0) && (strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") != 0) ){
            numfile++;
        }
    }
    // closedir(directory);
    rewinddir(directory);
    return numfile;
}

void directorios(char *dir){
    DIR *directory = NULL;
    char subdir[32] = ".";
    struct dirent *ent = NULL;
    
    directory = opendir(dir);
    printf("Directorio actual: \"%s\"", dir);
    printf(" -> numero de elementos: %i", total_archivos(directory)); // aqui llamo a la funcion el cual al ejecutar, el programa se detiene.
    printf("\n");

    while( (ent = readdir(directory)) != NULL ){
        if ( (strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") != 0) && (strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") != 0) ){ 
            printf("\t%s", ent->d_name);
            if (ent->d_type == DT_DIR){
                printf(" - Directorio\n");
                strcpy(subdir, ent->d_name);
            }else{
                printf(" - archivo\n");
            }
        }
    }

    if (strcmp(subdir, ".") != 0){
        directorios(subdir);
    }
    
    closedir(directory);
}

int main(void){
    printf("Lectura de archivos\n");
    directorios(".");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema no es tanto la llamada a `total_archivos` sino lo que hace la función.

Fíjate en lo que haces en esa función justo antes del `return`:

```
closedir(directory);
return numfile;
```

En efecto, llamas a `closedir`. Al hacer eso, el puntero `directory` deja de ser válido. Tu programa usa dos variables con el mismo nombre, `directory`, una variable está en `total_archivos()` y la otra en `directorios()`, ambas son punteros de tipo `DIR` y ambas apuntan a la misma dirección de memoria, luego ambos punteros dejarán de ser válidos.

Lo que sucede después es que, volviendo a la función `directorios`, intentas leer las entradas del directorio:

```
while( (ent = readdir(directory)) != NULL ){
```

Pero claro, esto ya no funciona porque `directory` ya no apunta a una entrada válida.

Todo se soluciona eliminando la llamada a `closedir` que haces en `total_archivos`.

> Sigue deteniéndose

Vale, esto es porque tienes que resetear el estado de `directory`. En la función `total_archivos` estás navegando por el contenido del directorio para contar cuántos archivos hay. Dejas de leer cuando `readdir` te avisa que no hay más elementos en ese directorio. Luego sales de la función e intentas recorrer nuevamente el directorio ... pero el puntero interno sigue estando al final del directorio.

El funcionamiento de todo este entramado, a grandes rasgos, es el siguiente:

`DIR` es una estructura con diversa información necesaria para interactuar el con el sistema de archivos. Uno de esos valores que guarda es una lista a los elementos contenidos dentro de dicho directorio. Esta lista se recorre con un puntero y ese puntero es actualizado en cada llamada a `readdir`. Cuando `readdir` te devuelve un `NULL` es porque ese puntero ha alcanzado el final de la lista ... y ahí se quedará hasta que lo reposiciones al inicio del listado.

Como ambas variables `directory` apuntan a la misma estructura `DIR`, aunque abandones la función, el puntero interno que te permite iterar por el contenido del directorio sigue apuntando al final de la lista y es por eso que no consigues listar el contenido del archivo.

Para forzar a que dicho puntero interno vuelva al inicio del directorio debes usar la función  `rewinddir`:

```
int total_archivos(DIR *directory){

    // ...

    rewinddir(directory);
    return numfile;
}
```

Comment: Sigue deteniéndose, pero lo que yo entiendo le estoy pasando el atributo `dir` a la función `total_archivos` como valor y no como referencia, por lo que es nuevo dato con otra dirección de memoria lo que no debe de afectar el de proceso principal.

Comment: @tecnobyte lo que estás copiando es la dirección de memoria, no el contenido de dicha dirección de memoria. Es decir, lo que consigues es que ambos punteros apunten a la misma región de memoria ... piensa que los punteros sirven precisamente para eso

Comment: Tenias razón, no sabia que se tenia que reiniciar el directorio para que apunte de nuevo al iniciar, ya me funciono, gracias.